# Is there a way to skip the body in a python context?

Tags: python

How can I create a context (the `with` syntax) in python that could, in __enter__, skip the content and go directly to __exit__?

Or is there no other way then using an if like so:

```
with Context() as ctx:
    if ctx.proceed:
        # do some stuff...
```

Comment: This is an odd request.  It shouldn't be up to the context thingy to make this decision.  If you have a condition that prevents operation, then you should raise an exception.  It's then up to the caller to handle that.

Comment: For reference: ["*Errors should never pass silently.*"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/). If I were to use your code I would prefer the context manager to raise an exception ("*Okay, the context is preventing access. I must handle this case correctly.*") rather than simply doing nothing ("*Why the hell won't this run?!*").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This control should be within the context, not the manager!

```py
with my_context() as foo:  # opportunity to pass args to my_context
    pass  # do nothing and leave context
```

If you want to put the features in the manager, just put them there - this might be simplified by an `@contextlib.contextmanager`

```py
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def my_context(arg1=None):
    if arg1 is None:
        # opportunity to do things
        yield "simplified context"
    else:
        # do things with arg1
        ctx = "normal context"
        try:
            yield ctx
        finally:
            "opportunity to clean up from Exception in caller"
```

Finally, if you want to *asynchronously* end your context, consider `asyncio` or spawning a `subprocess` or `multiprocess` and end it when say, time's up

Answer (score 1):

This is what exceptions are for.

```
try:
    with Context() as ctx:
        # Do some stuff
except MyContextException:
    print("whoops")
```

Comment: note this won't call `__exit__` if the Exception occurs in `__enter__`, only during the `# Do some stuff` _within_ the context

Comment: True.  Since we know we're firing an exception, good engineering practice would do the clean up before doing the `raise`.